# UIViewPropertyAnimator different behaviour on iOS10 and iOS11 reversing an animation. Bug on `isReversed` and `fractionComplete` properties?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios10, ios11, uiviewpropertyanimator

**THE PROBLEM**
Running the same code on iOS10 and iOS11 my UIViewPropertyAnimator has a different behaviour just after changing of his `.isReversed` property.
Everything is ok on iOS10. The animation problem happens on iOS11

**CONDITIONS**
It's true for any animations, not only for a particular one, and it is verifiable both by watching the animation and within the code.
It happens both on simulators and real devices.

**DETAILS**
Once created a UIViewPropertyAnimator with his animation, during its running I just call `.pauseAnimation()` and change the `.isReversed` property to **true**. After that I resume the animation calling:

```swift
continueAnimation(withTimingParameters parameters: UITimingCurveProvider?, durationFactor: CGFloat)
```

at this point on iOS10 the animation smoothly changes his verse, on iOS11 it stops immediately and reverses itself with a bit frames lag.

If in code I check the value of `.fractionComplete` (called on my UIViewPropertyAnimator object it gives me back the completion of the animation in his percent value, starting from 0.0 and ending at 1.0)
just after `.continueAnimation(...`
- On iOS 10 it remains for a few moments like if the animation is continuing and only after some fractions of time jumps to his complementary.
- On iOS 11 it jumps suddenly on his complementary

On the documentation there are non updates related to this, just a couple of new properties for the UIViewPropertyAnimator but not used because I'm targeting iOS10

Could be a bug or I'm missing something!?

---

*Little update*: just tested, same behaviour on iOS 11.0.1 and on iOS 11.1 beta1

As linked in the comment, this happens only with a non-linear curve!

Comment: Someone seems to have similar problems: rdar://problem/34674968 [link](https://openradar.appspot.com/34674968)

Comment: Try setting new timing parameters instead of passing nil:     `let paras = UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 0.8, initialVelocity: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100))` and `animator.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: paras, durationFactor: 1)`

Comment: In my case I would use `continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve.easeIn) ...)` but it has the described problem. As you can find inside the link on my previous comment the problems is present performing **animations with a non-linear curve**!
Indeed if I use `continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve.linear) ...)`, **using a linear curve**, it hasn't any problem! But I will try with your `trimmingParamenters`!

Comment: In my case I had the "jumping" only when the configured property animator had a non-linear curve and then passing nil for `withTimingParameters`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been fighting this for quite a while as well, but then I noticed the `scrubsLinearly` property that was added to `UIViewPropertyAnimator` in iOS 11:

> Defaults to true. Provides the ability for an animator to pause and scrub either linearly or using the animator’s current timing.

Note that the default of this property is `true`, which seems to cause a conflict with using a non-linear animation curve. That might also explain why the issue is not present when using a linear timing function.

Setting `scrubsLinearly` to `false`, the animator seems to work as expected:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.25, curve: .easeOut) {
   ...
}
animator.scrubsLinearly = false
```

Comment: You'r a Genius! Thank you ^.^

Answer (score 1):

1. On iOS 11, `fractionComplete` will be reversed (that is, `1 - originalFractionComplete`) after you reverse animation by `animator.isReversed = true`.
2. Spring animation that have less than 0.1s duration will complete instantly.

So you may originally want the reversed animation runs 90% of the entire animation duration, but on iOS 11, the reversed animation actually runs 10% duration because `isReversed` changed, and that 10% duration is less than 0.1s, so the animation will be completed instantly and looks like no animation happened.

How to fix?

For iOS 10 backward compatibility, copy the `fractionComplete` value before you reverse animation and use it for `continueAnimation`.

e.g.

```
let fraction = animator.fractionComplete
animator.isReversed = true
animator.continueAnimation(...*fraction*...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions, but no one didn't work for me. I wrote my solution and everything is fine now. My solution:

1. take an image of the screen and show it
2. finish animation
3. start new animation for old state
4. pause the animation and set progress (1 - original progress)
5. remove screen image and continue animation

   ```
   switch pan.state {
   ...
   case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
       let velocity = pan.velocity(in: view)
       let reversed: Bool

       if abs(velocity.y) < 200 {
           reversed = progress < 0.5
       } else {
           switch state {
           case .shown:
               reversed = velocity.y < 0
           case .minimized:
               reversed = velocity.y > 0
           }
       }

       if reversed {
           let overlayView = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
           view.addSubview(overlayView)
           animator?.stopAnimation(false)
           animator?.finishAnimation(at: .end)
           startAnimation(state: state.opposite)
           animator?.pauseAnimation()
           animator?.fractionComplete = 1 - progress
           overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
           animator?.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0.5)
       } else {
           animator?.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)
       }
   ```

And the animation curve option must be `linear`.

```
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .linear) {
        startAnimation()
    }
```